# Automating DB Backup Copies

Tags: database, batch-file, ftp, backup, winrar

I have a specific task to accomplish and doing it manually takes many hours, so I'd like an automated way to do it.

**Relevant Info:**

- DB is 80GB (35GB compressed with best compression in WinRAR)
- DB is across a VPN connection in the cloud
- Want to compress DB, copy back to Enterprise
- Copying via SMB almost always will result in corruption, FTP is preferred method across the VPN to prevent the corruption
- Would like to verify MD5 checksums before copying, and after to make sure it is not corrupted.

**Manual Steps:**

- MD5 checksum on DB backup
- Use WinRAR to compress latest backup with best compression
- MD5 checksum on rar archive (takes about an hour)
- FTP the rar file over the VPN to Enterprise center
- MD5 checksum on rar archive 
- Uncompress
- MD5 checksum on DB backup

In all reality I can probably skip doing the checksum on the rar archive. Call me anal retentive if you will. I think the best thing would be to find an MD5 checksum command line utility, and do the MD5 checksum and WinRAR compression via a batch script. I am unsure how to do the FTP part though. Suggestions? Thanks guys. Cheers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to ftp with a batch file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16158138/how-to-ftp-with-a-batch-file)

Answer (score 0):

Windows has an `FTP.EXE` which uses passive file transfers and can be scripted with the `-s:file` switch.

If you use `7-Zip` instead of `WinRar` then you will probably get superior compression on the highest settings, and it can create `ZIP` and well as `7z` files.

Another advantage for you is that 7-Zip has a switch `7z l -slt file.zip` which you can get the checksum from the archive without another calculation.

You can download the backup again to do another checksum.

I put this in an answer block so it's easier to read the points.