# Is it possible to upload ftp files from SQL server without xp_cmdshell?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ftp

Ideally would like to run something from a SQL query or SQL agent job to FTP upload a file to an external site, but cannot use xp_cmdshell.

Comment: Like OPENROWSET?

Comment: There is an available SSIS Script that will handle FTP uploads etc. It can be seen [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2b7cf6b5-d16d-44cd-954d-68e9ba98ee91/ssis-script-task-that-ftps-files?forum=sqlintegrationservices).

Comment: @Laughing Vergil I bookmarked that for the future - thanks!  As of now we don't have SSIS available though....

Comment: OPENROWSET doesn't need SSIS

Comment: @scsimon Do you have any sample code?  No clue how that would work to export a file through FTP...

Comment: [Here](https://sql-programmers.com/tsql-openrowset-in-sql-server) is a good thread, and [here](http://www.theboreddba.com/Categories/miscellaneous/Using-OPENROWSET-instead-of-a-Linked-Server.aspx) is another.

Comment: I think that this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37792082 - covers the issue completely. FTP is not accessible over OpenRowset.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You need to split your work into two separate tasks:

1. How to run executable or a batch program from within SQL Server without resorting to xp_cmdshell.
   An example of how to do it can be found in:
   https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2014/replace-xpcmdshell-command-line-use-with-sql-server-agent/.
   You should modify this example to suit your particular needs. Suggested stored procedure would:

   - run command passed as a parameter in created on-the-fly SQL job  (indicate CmdExec subsystem)
   - wait for SQL job completion (query msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity) or kill the job if predefined timeout value has been reached
   - return results of job execution (query msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory)
   - delete the job

Note:  Full version of SQL Server required. If you are using express version, you would have to manually define a windows scheduled task.

2. How to send a file via ftp using a batch program.
   Please see:
   [How to ftp with a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16158138/how-to-ftp-with-a-batch-file)